# Static types, polymorphism and specialization

Tags: haskell, types

When I first learned Haskell, I very quickly came to love parametric polymorphism. It's a delightfully simple idea that works astonishingly well. The whole "if it compiles it usually works right" thing is mostly due to parametric polymorphism, IMHO.

But the other day, something occurred to me. I can write `foo` as a polymorphic function. But when `bar` calls `foo`, it will do so with a specific set of argument types. Or, if `bar` itself is polymorphic, then *its* caller will assign definite types. By induction, it seems that if you were to take any valid Haskell program and analyse the *entire codebase*, you can statically determine the type of every single thing in the entire program.

This, in a sense, is a bit like C++ templates. There is no *run-time* polymorphism, only *compile-time* polymorphism. A Haskell compiler could choose to generate separate machine code for every type at which each polymorphic function is called. Most Haskell compilers don't, but you could implement one if you wanted to.

Only if you start adding Haskell extensions (`ExistentialQuantification` is the obvious one) do you start to get real *run-time* polymorphism, where you have values who's type cannot be statically computed.

Oh, yeah, my question?

1. Are the statements above actually correct?
2. Is there a widely-used *name* for this property?

Comment: I recently encountered [this document](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~greg/cs256sp2005/lec15.txt) which is very illuminating.

Comment: Here is a web archive link to the aforementioned document.  (Greg Morisett 2005, [Harvard CS256 Lecture 15: Polymorphism](https://web.archive.org/web/20080906235653/http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~greg/cs256sp2005/lec15.txt))

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Haskell (with no extensions) permits polymorphic recursion, and this feature alone makes it impossible to statically specialize a program to a completely monomorphic one.  Here is a program that will print an N-deep nested list, where N is a command-line parameter:

```
import System

foo :: Show a => Int -> a -> IO ()
foo 0 x = print x
foo n x = foo (n-1) [x]

main = do [num_lists] <- getArgs
          foo (read num_lists) 0
```

In the first call to `foo`, `a` has type `Int`.  In the next recursive call, it has type `[Int]`, then `[[Int]]`, and so forth.

If polymorphic recursion is prohibited, then I believe it's possible to statically specialize a program.

Comment: Wow. OK, now can you think up a _useful_ example of polymorphic recursion? ;-) [I'm guessing that's going to end up being quite complex...]

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid The standard examples involve working with perfectly balanced trees: `data BTree a = Leaf a | BTree (a,a)`.

Comment: Still, just because you can't make a monomorphic version doesn't mean the types exist at runtime: GHC gets away with type erasure completely for most programs. (Though it doesn't always get away with typeclass dictionary erasure -- especially in a program like this one!)

Comment: This does not compile ... it says "The equation(s) for `foo' have two arguments, but its type `a -> IO ()' has only one". And bypassing the type specification it complains about not being able to construct an infinite type. But typing it as `Int -> a -> IO ()` works!

Comment: Even if polymorphic recursion is prohibited in Haskell (like it used to be), it possible to encode polymorphic recursion using a class.  So just prohibiting polymorphic recursion is not enough to guarantee static specialization.

Comment: I went away and had a think about this. In the example above, it seems to me that the problem isn't so much that we don't _know_ what the types are, it's that the set of types is not necessarily finite. (E.g., `foo (-7)`.) Even if it is finite, the quantity depends on a run-time value. But you could imagine implementing N layers of recursion and giving up if that is exceeded. Does anybody have an example where even that wouldn't work?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, if you gave up when it was exceeded, surely that counts as not working?

Answer (score 14):

Yep, I've thought about this too. Basically, the idea is that it seems like you could implement Haskell 98, but not some of the language extensions to it, using polymorphism-by-multiinstantiation instead of polymorphism-by-boxing.

You can get some insight into this by trying to implement some Haskell features as C++ libraries (as you note, C++ does polymorphism-by-multiinstatiation). What you find is that you can do everything that Haskell can do, except that it's impossible to have polymorphic values, which includes references to polymorphic functions.

What this looks like is that if you have

```
template<typename T>
void f(T);           // f :: a -> IO ()
```

you can take the address of a particular instantiation to pass around as a function pointer at runtime:

```
&f<int>
```

but you cannot take the address of a template (`&f`). This makes sense: templates are a purely compile-time construct. It also makes sense that if you're doing polymorphism by multiinstantiation, you can have a pointer to any particular instantiation, but you cannot have a pointer to the polymorphic function itself, because at the machine code level, there isn't one.

So where does Haskell use polymorphic values? At first glance it seems like a good rule of thumb of is "anywhere you have to write an explicit forall". So `PolymorphicComponents`, `Rank2Types`, `RankNTypes`, and `ImpredicativeTypes` are obvious no-nos. You can't translate this to C++:

```
data MkList = MkList (forall a. a -> [a])
singleton = MkList (\x -> [x])
```

On the other hand, `ExistentialQuantification` is doable in at least some cases: it means having a non-template class with a template constructor (or more generally, a class whose constructor is templated on more things than the class itself).

If in Haskell you have:

```
data SomeShow = forall a. Show a => SomeShow a
instance Show SomeShow where show (SomeShow a) = show a
```

you can implement this in C++ as:

```
// a function which takes a void*, casts it to the given type, and
// calls the appropriate show() function (statically selected based
// on overload resolution rules)
template<typename T>
String showVoid(void *x)
{
    show(*(T*)x);
}

class SomeShow
{
    private:
        void *m_data;
        String (*m_show)(void*); // m_show :: Any -> String

    public:
        template<typename T>
        SomeShow(T x)
            : m_data(new T(x)) // memory management issues here, but that's orthogonal
            , m_show(&showVoid<T>)
        {
        }

        String show()
        {
            // alternately we could declare the top-level show() as a friend and
            // put this there
            return m_show(m_data);
        }
};

// C++ doesn't have type classes per se, but it has overloading, which means
// that interfaces are implicit: where in Haskell you would write a class and
// instances, in C++ you just write a function with the same name for each type
String show(SomeShow x)
{
    return x.show();
}
```

In both languages you have a non-polymorphic type with a polymorphic constructor.

So we have shown that there are some language extensions you can implement and some you can't, but what about the other side of the coin: is there anything in Haskell 98 that you can't implement? Judging by the fact that you need a language extension (`ExplicitForAll`) to even write a forall, you would think that the answer is no. And you would almost be right, but there's two wrinkles: type classes and polymorphic recursion. Type classes are typically implemented using dictionary passing: each instance declaration results in a record of functions, which are implicitly passed around wherever they're needed.

So for Monad for example you would have:

```
data MonadDict m = MonadDict { 
    return :: forall a. a -> m a,
    (>>=)  :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
}
```

Well would you look at those foralls! You can't write them explicitly, but in dictionary passing implementations, even in Haskell 98, classes with polymorphic methods result in records containing polymorphic functions. Which if you're trying to implement the whole thing using multiinstantion is obviously going to be a problem. You can almost get away without dictionary passing because, if you stick to Haskell 98, instances are almost always global and statically known. Each instance results in some polymorphic functions, but because which one to call is almost always known at compile time, you almost never need to pass references to them around at runtime (which is good, because you can't). The tradeoff is that you need to do whole-program compilation, because otherwise instances are no longer statically known: they might be in a different module. And the exception is polymorphic recursion, which practically requires you to build up a dictionary at runtime. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10535629/626288) for more details on that. Polymorphic recursion kills the multiinstantiation approach even without type classes: see the comment about `BTree`s. (Also `ExistentialQuantification` *plus* classes with polymorphic methods is no longer doable, because you would have to again start storing pointers to polymorphic functions.)

Comment: Do you mean `ExistentialQuantification` instead of `ExplicitQuantification`?

Comment: Obviously, C++ can not _only_ do polymorphism-by-multiinstatiation. The `ExistentialQuantification` stuff can be done with virtual inheritance, which sadly is not automatically compatible with the template approach and closer to Java than to Haskell.

Comment: @is7s, right, I was in a bit of a hurry and didn't have time to proof read. I'll do that now.

Comment: @leftroundabout, can you elaborate on that? It sounds interesting. I haven't really wrapped my head around what virtual inheritance means beyond it being a not-so-satisfactory solution to the diamond inheritance problem.

Comment: This is _also_ a fantastic answer!

Comment: @glaebhoerl thanks for this fantastic answer, but you can actually implement `singleton = MkList (\x -> [x])` in C++ in a type-safe manner. You need a `MkList` class that has a `virtual castable_list<any> operator()(any)` method, and a non virtual `castable_list<T> operator()(T)` that casts the argument to `any` calls the virtual `operator()` and casts the result back to a `castable_list<T>`. Instead of a virtual `operator()` you could also have `function<castable_list<any>(any)>f` as a member field, and initialize that field with a constructor that accepts a generic `T -> castable_list<T>`.

Comment: BTW, I know that my comment doesn't invalidate any point you make in your answer, just the statement "You can't translate this to C++". A literal translation is possible, though C++ muddies this a bit since ad-hoc polymorphism through class template specialization might not play well with this approach. For instance castable_list<T> might have a very odd specialization for a certain type T. I guess the translation is literal, if there' s no such specialization.

Comment: @enobayram I've been staring at your comment for 5-10 minutes and can't seem to piece it together in my head (in particular, what's `castable_list`?)... could you throw the code up as a gist or something? :)

Comment: @glaebhoerl sorry, my comment does look like a mess. I had a picture of the solution in my head when I wrote it, but after 5 months I had to decipher it myself too :) Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/enobayram/dce92b468423a8ef6882

Comment: @enobayram Hmm. This seems to be taking advantage of the fact that (using Haskell types) you can instantiate `a -> [a]` at `Dynamic -> [Dynamic]`, which you can then cast any `b` into and out of -- plus the fact that in C++ there's no parametricity and you essentially know `forall a. Typeable a`. I'm not sure how far it generalizes to other higher-ranked things (the fact that you need to use `fmap` on the output, or your `list_cast` in the C++ case, is troubling). But it seems vaguely similar to what gradual typing systems do implicitly...

Answer (score 8):

[Whole program compilers](http://mirror.seize.it/papers/Code%20Optimization%20Techniques%20for%20Lazy%20Functional%20Languages.pdf) take advantage of global access to type information to make very aggressive optimizations, as you describe above. Examples include [JHC](http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/) and [MLton](http://www.mlton.org/). GHC with inlining is partially "whole program" as well, for similar reasons. Other techniques that take advantage of global information include [super compilation](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/downloads/slides-rethinking_supercompilation_29_sep_2010.pdf).

Note that you can massively increase code size by specializing polymorphic functions at all the types they're used at -- this then needs heavy inlining to reduce code back to normal values. Managing this is a challenge.

Comment: Right. So it _is_ as static as I suspected then? I find it interesting that this fact is _hardly ever_ a problem. :-D And yes, I think the way GHC implements this (with the specialize pragma and all) is really nice.

Comment: There are still unknown function calls. Polymorphic recursion, other kinds of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Even if you specialize all polymorphic functions to their actual types you'll find that many of them end up with identical code.  E.g., all specializations of a polymorphic function where the actual types are boxed will end up the same.  This will reduce code volume.