# Constraint Inference from Instances

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Foo where

data D a = D a
class Foo b

instance (Num a) => Foo (D a)

f :: (Foo (D a)) => a -> a
f x = x+1
```

GHC complains that it cannot deduce `Num a` in `f`. I would like this constraint to be inferred from the (non-overlapping) instance of `Foo` for `D a`.

I know I *could* use a GADT for `D` and add the constraint `Num a` there, but I'm hoping to not have to pollute the constructor for `D` with lots of unnecessary constraints. Is there any hope of this ever happening, and is it possible now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrow `=>` is *directional*. It means that *if* `Num a` holds then `Foo (D a)`. It does not mean that if `Foo (D a)` holds then `Num a` holds.

The knowledge that there are (and will never be) any overlapping instances for `Foo (D a)` should imply that the reverse implication is also true, but (a) GHC doesn't know this and (b) GHC's instance machinery is not set up to use this knowledge.

To actually compile functions that use type classes, it's not enough for GHC to merely prove that a type must be an instance of a class. It has to actually come up with a **specific instance declaration** that provides definitions of the member functions. We need a constructive proof, not just an existence proof.

To identify an instance of class C, it can either reuse one that will be chosen by the *caller* of the function being compiled, or it must know the types involved concretely enough to select a single instance from those available. The function being compiled will only be passed an instance for C if it has a constraint for C; otherwise the function must be sufficiently monomorphic that it can only use a single instance.

Considering your example specifically, we can see that f has a constraint for `Foo (D a)`, so we can rely on the caller providing that for us. But the caller isn't going to give us an instance for `Num a`. Even if you presume that we know from the `Num a` constraint on `Foo (D a)` that there must be such an instance out there somewhere, we have no idea what `a` is, so which definition of `+` should we invoke? We can't even call *another* function that works for any `Num a` but is defined outside the class, because they will all have the `Num a` constraint and thus expect us to identify an instance for them. Knowing that there *is* an instance without having *having* the instance is just not useful.

It isn't at all obvious, but what you're actually asking GHC to do is to do a runtime switch on the type `a` that arrives at runtime. This is impossible, because we're supposed to be emitting code that works for any type in `Num`, even types that don't exist yet, or whose instances don't exist yet.

A similar idea that *does* work is when you have a constraint on the *class* rather than on the *instance*. For example:

```
class Num a => Foo a 

f :: Foo a => a -> a
f x = x + 1
```

But this only works because we know that *all* `Foo` instances must have a corresponding `Num` instance, and thus all callers of a function polymorphic in `Foo a` know to also select a `Num` instance. So even without knowing the particular `a` in order to select a `Num` instance, `f` knows that its caller will also provide a `Num` instance along with the `Foo` instance.

In your case, the *class* `Foo` knows nothing about `Num`. In other examples `Num` might not even be defined in code accessible to the module where the class `Foo` is defined. It's the *class* that sets the required information that has to be provided to call a function that is polymorphic in the type class, and those polymorphic functions have to be able to work without any knowledge specific to a certain instance.

So the `Num a => Foo (D a)` instance *can't* store the `Num` instance - indeed, the instance definition is also polymorphic in `a`, so it's not able to select a particular instance to store even if there was space! So even though `f` might be able to know that there *is* a `Num a` instance from `Foo (D a)` (if we presume certain knowledge that no overlapping could ever be involved), it still needs a `Num a` constraint in order to require its callers to select a `Num` instance for it to use.

Comment: "It isn't at all obvious, but what you're actually asking GHC to do is to do a runtime switch on the type `a` that arrives at runtime." I was about to object that, absent GADT tricks, at runtime everything needs to be monomorphic and therefore the value of the type variable `a` must be known at compile time, but [that's not actually the case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10535629/1186208). Still, I don't understand why the runtime aspect is significant here.

Comment: @ChristianConkle Coming up with a `Num` instance *inside* a function (not declared in the interface via a constraint) would require knowing the type so that you can find the instance. Since `f` is polymorphic, it can be invoked on different types at different times, so the switch on the type would have to be performed at runtime (which is impossible, because types don't exist **at all** at runtime, let alone a complete dictionary mapping types to Num instances). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 7):

I am guessing this would break for overlapping instances, and therefore is not inferred in general. That is, you could have

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
...
instance (Num a) => Foo (D a)

instance Foo (D Bool)
```

and then your desired inference would certainly *not* be sound.

EDIT: Looking more closely at [the documentation](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap), it is possible to have

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Foo where

data D a = D a
class Foo b

instance (Num a) => Foo (D a)

f :: (Foo (D a)) => a -> a
f x = x+1
```

and then in a *separate* file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
module Bar where

import Foo

instance Foo Bool

test = f True
```

That is, the documentation implies only *one* of the modules defining the two instances needs to have the `OverlappingInstances` flag, so if `Foo.f` were definable as this, you could make another module `Bar` break type safety completely. Note that with GHC's separate compilation, `f` would be compiled completely without knowledge of the module `Bar`.

Comment: I agree this would be harder with `OverlappingInstances`, but it should be possible without it I think. Even with overlapping instances, if a constraint is common between all instances, it could be inferred.

Comment: @Eric The problem, as shown by my edited example, is that GHC's separate compilation + open world assumption for classes prevents on principle almost any knowledge about "all instances" of a class.